# If statement in sql server how to get values from sub query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I trying get results from diferent tables. 
If name is 1111 then SELECT * FROM TABLE 1
If name is 2222 then SELECT * FROm TABLE 2

```
SELECT CASE 

WHEN type='111111'

THEN (SELECT * FROM db1)
ELSE (SELECT * FROM db2)
FROM db_name
```

Where is problem?

Comment: The problem is in the syntax, I guess: SQL does not let you do it.

Comment: where you expect SQL to search for "type" value? (so it can compare to 111111)

Comment: case does not allow to return result set. In stead it returns an expression only. Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181765(v=sql.105).aspx for further details. For this scenario, you can use if statement to handle. Or another way is to craete query dynamically and execute that.

Comment: Hi user3747585, issue solved with the query given below or not.

Comment: hey u miss END keyword after ELSE Statement

Comment: @Azar yes it work but complicated get multiple values

Comment: Any junk values are coming?

Answer (score 1):

Try as below:

```
SELECT 
CASE 
  WHEN COLUMN1='XYZ' THEN (SELECT SINGLE_COL FROM DB1)
  ELSE (SELECT SINGLE_COL FROM DB1) 
END 
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Where the inner query must return single value.

Answer (score 0):

this will give u the answer

```
Select db1.* from db1 join db_name on 1=1 where db_name = '1111111'
union all
Select db2.* from db2 join db_name on 1=1 where db_name <> '1111111'
```